# Regular expression replace in Visual Studio

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2010, replace, pattern-matching

Using Visual Studio 2010 I would like to do a project level regular expression replace as below.

Find: `#region {any string here}`

Replace: `#region - string from above -`

I tried the below:

```
region\s'{[^]+}'

region '{[^]+}'

region {:q}
```

But the IDE complains about an incorrect pattern. How can I fix this?

Comment: [^] is not (missing thing)... try '\{[^}]+\}'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ahhh, Visual Studio regexes... They shouldn't be called a regex since they diverge to much of what is "standard"

I fired up VS and after some trial and error this works:

search:

```
\#region \{{.*}\}
```

replace:

```
#region - \1 -
```

Answer (score 5):

Try:

Search: `{\#region:b+}{.*}`

Replace: `\1 - \2 -`

If you're specifically searching for the '{' and '}',

Search: `{\#region:b+}\{{.*}\}`

With quotes:

Search: `{\#region:b+}{'.*'}`

To remove quotes:

Search: `{\#region:b+}'{.*}'`